# Variance in academic fecundity during and after graduate school

Tags: publications

Some people used to be prolific when they were working on their PhDs, but years after graduation, they hardly published a single paper. Why?

Also, some faculty members published great papers while working on their PhDs that received dozens of citations, but few years later and after they started leading their own research, most of their published work barely got any citation. How come?

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting here? Your question clearly shows that people are different. You'd have to look at each case individually.

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth: it is quite the contrary! I am conspicuously asking about the  difference in performance of the same people before and after they obtained their PhDs, but I am presenting two different scenarios for clarity.

Comment: I do not think this question is too broad or opinion-based. Question itself is quite specific. The answers may vary a lot, depending on their context. I am voting to keep this open.

Comment: Here's a similar (but more narrowly scoped) question: [Why do some individuals who are productive PhD students at leading Western institutions, then publish infrequently as faculty in their home country?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/38944/17254). From a more personal perspective there's also [After successfully publishing papers during my Post-Doc, why am I now having trouble publishing as a tenure track academic?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/81369/17254).

Comment: I still think that the question can not be answered. I've given three more answers in comments below @Buffy's answer below.

Comment: @Scientist. Thanks! that's the spirit of scientists. Constructivism prevails despite stochastic disturbances.

Comment: @Anyon. Thanks for sharing! Though the first one is a very narrow case - limited to those engaged in academia abroad, and the second one is a personal case.

Comment: Thank you all. I was guessing that during PhD, some people are lucky to be part of a productive and collaborative habitat. But upon leaving the nest, they end up where they are. Still. I wanted to know other possible reasons, as I might be wrong

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are more reasons, but here are two positive reasons.

Some people get a job that stresses teaching more than research and so they put their focus there. It can be a rewarding life, actually. Lots of teaching and a bit of research. Maybe less stress. Of course this is an unlikely scenario at an R1 university.

Some people, after gaining tenure and leading a fairly large group of graduate students in a lab or research group, are willing to let the students gain the glory and don't add themselves as co-author, even though it might be appropriate. This isn't a good path before tenure, but can be afterwards. So they are doing research but, by feeding ideas to them, the students gain the credit for it.

Comment: Yet others have benefited from good mentoring as grad students, but can't seem to hit their stride once they're faculty.

Comment: Yet others get married and have children, some with special needs, and do not have the time to do more than the minimum their school requires.

Comment: Yet others struggle with mental health issues, or loved ones with mental health issues.

Comment: There are so many reasons why people are or choose to be not among the most productive even though they may have been at an earlier stage in their lives. There's really no general reason -- people's lives move in so many different directions once they grow out of their 20s.

Comment: @Wolfgang, I guess you nailed it on the first comment.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, One reason is that too many people never develop, or give up, a circle of collaborators when they finish their degree. Such a circle is one of the most valuable things you can take away from grad school. If you don't have one, then work to build it.

Comment: @Buffy. Thanks! once again, you have my back with your genuine answer.